# Trying to replace text and dynamically add link using Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, hyperlink

So a pretty simple thing in general, just not sure how to go about executing it. This page http://www.juju.com.au/blog/ has blog posts that have […] at the end. I want to grab the link from the post title and replace […] with a "read more" link. Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us What you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

so i assume you want:

```
[<a onclick:"function(postNum)">...</a>]
```

where postNum will be different for each post. 
Then you want:

```
<script> function(postNum) {
//SOME CODE
} </script>
```

the some code you could either make an AJAX call to retrieve full text, or what you could do is when you load the page you load the full text but hide after certain characters #, and inside the function you can unhide that text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are more efficient ways but this should work for your scenario.

```
$('div.FeedContent').each(function() {
    var link = $(this).prev('h2').find('a').attr("href");
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('[…]', '<a href="' + link + '">[…]</a>'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
$(".FeedContent").each(function () {
    TitleURL = $(this).prev().find("a").prop("href");
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("[…]","<a href='" + TitleURL + "'>…</a>"));
});
```

[**And a working Fidle**](http://jsfiddle.net/72Bu8/)